# Movable Popup Directive makes Popup Jump to corner of Screen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hello I am very new to AngularJs but I modified a pretty cool directive that allows me to drag a modal popup... however when  I click to move it, it jumps to the left hand corner of the screen.

**JS:**

```
(function () {

    var schemaWizardApp = angular.module('schemaWizardApp');

    schemaWizardApp.directive('modaldraggable', function ($document) {
        "use strict";
        return function (scope, element) {
            var startX = 400,
                startY = 400,
                x = 400,
                y = 400;
            element= angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog"));
            console.log("added directive");
            element.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                cursor: 'move'
            });

            element.on('mousedown', function (event) {
                // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                event.preventDefault();
                startX = event.screenX - x;
                startY = event.screenY - y;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
            });

            function mousemove(event) {
                y = event.screenY - startY;
                x = event.screenX - startX;
                element.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left: x + 'px'
                });
            }

            function mouseup() {
                $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

**CSS:**

```
 .modal-dialog {
        position: fixed;
        left: 40%;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't... I can try to work on one

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is I had to set x = 400,y = 400; to whatever value on the screen I wanted.